# How to reduce a processing time - parallelize pandas dataframe?

Tags: python, database, pandas, dataframe, parallel-processing

I am accessing a large CSV file, having more than 20 million rows and 200+ columns.

My code is taking too much time in the following portion:

```
def Myfunction(df):
   if df['3.3'] ==  1 or df['2.3'] ==  1 or df['1.3'] ==  1 or df['4'] == 1:
       df['A1'] = 'A1'
       df['AZ B1'] = df[basic_clean('AZ col')]
       df['CZ Cat'] = df[basic_clean('Cate name')]
       df['CZ Sub'] = df[basic_clean('SubName')]
       df['CZ Com'] = df[basic_clean('Comm_Name')]

   else:
       df['A1'] = 'Not A1'
       df['AZ B1'] = df[basic_clean('Fam name')]
       df['CZ Cat'] = df[basic_clean('C Name')]
       df['CZ Sub'] = df[basic_clean('Sub Name')]
       df['CZ Com'] = df[basic_clean('C Name')]
   return df
```

Here, `basic_clean()` is a function, it formats the text ( to uppercase ), doesn't take much time. I read somewhere to use parallelizing pandas dataframe but didn't fine any good material regarding this.

Comment: What is `basic_clean('Fam name')` doing? How can we help without understanding what your code does?

Comment: I'm not sure this does what you think it does: `df['3.3'] ==  1`.

Comment: @IanS there is a column named 3.3 it is checking value of that is one or not.

Comment: @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ i mentioned above basic_clean() method take an string argument and return its's upper case value

Comment: Why do you need a function for that? Are you passing it as the column name? Can you please show some data that we can work with?

Answer (score 0):

### How to reduce a processing time?

In the above described use-case, the best improvement will come from an initial one-shot pre-transforming the said `CSV`-file-A into a `CSV`-file-B. A "Stream"-based large-file processing will in most cases be faster, due to having all transformations stream-"aligned" and also file-IO-"aligned" and stream-processing will exhibit minimised file-IO / dataflow overheads ( be it on spinning disks, SSD, NAS or other type of a remote file access ). A good implementation of this step can guarantee minimum process-latency and also can efficiently mask a majority of this step latency from the transformed file post-processing processes ( importers ).
<sub>( 've used this sort of approaches in huge telco-CDR-stream-processing ( way larger than your scales of some ~ `[2E+7,2E+2]` files, so can be pretty sure I can well compare best, better, just-enough and poor approaches at scale ) )</sub>

Having done that pre-transformation step, the python-side will enjoy not to bear any such block-workload and will just process a dataframe, imported from "correctly" pre-formatted `CSV`-file-B.

Parallelism on fileIO-bound operations will not help in most cases due to extremely high IO-latencies ( ~ 10+ [ms] for fileIO instead of ~ [ns] for CPU/MEM-IO ), unmanageably limited dataflow bandwidths and due to easy resource-contention ( blocking ).